# OpenCart CMS Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have made a story website with OpenCart CMS, after 3 month it gives this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12723 bytes) in /home/pasarg24/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_url.php on line 30
```

my domain name is [www.pasargadfarsh.ir](http://pasargadfarsh.ir)

[image]

Comment: increase your memory size..

Comment: @devpro The Memory size is 512M, How it should be?

Comment: ini_set('memory_limit','1024M'); inside the file.

Comment: I changed `memory_limit` of php.ini file to 1024M and then it gived me this error `Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 1054605312) (tried to allocate 19104 bytes) in /home/pasarg24/public_html/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_library_url.php on line 30`

Comment: increase as per your script size...

Comment: The structure of directory show in above image,Please tell me what do you mean? Please show in the picture?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101690/discussion-between-saeed-gharedaghi-and-devpro).

Comment: I think, you should have to increase `post_max_size` and `max_execution_time`

Comment: I changed it but it gave me same error yet,my php.ini config is :
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 1024M;
max_execution_time = 64000;
post_max_size=16M;
upload_max_filesize = 16M;
safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.use_only_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.cookie_httponly = On;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 172800;
allow_url_fopen = on;
;display_errors = 1;
;error_reporting = E_ALL;

Comment: set `memory limit -1` (infinity) just for testing purpose.